# mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone tell me why on the first past (or sometimes 5th pass through) this code works. However I am getting a crash at random with the following message:

> __NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Here is the code:

```
if (![self.recentSearchesArray containsObject:self.filterParameters[@"includedKeywords"]]){

        [self.recentSearchesArray addObject:[self.filterParameters [@"includedKeywords"] mutableCopy]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[self.recentSearchesArray mutableCopy] forKey:@"RecentSearches"];
        [self.SavedSearchesTableView reloadData];
    }
```

The recent search array is an NSMutableArray declared as a `@property(strong, nonotomic)NSMutableArray *recentSearchesArray`

It is crashing when I am adding an object to the array.

**Edit**

My recent searches array is allocated like so:

```
if (!self.recentSearchesArray){
        self.recentSearchesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
```

My filtered parameters dictionary is allocated like so:

```
    self.filterParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:params];
```

params is an NSDictionary allocated like so:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.searchTerm forKey:@"includedKeywords"];
```

**Solution**

As per marked answer - NSUserDefaults was the issue:

```
self.recentSearchesArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"RecentSearches"];
```

This returned a NSArray instead of NSMutableArray. I never thought that was the case with NSUserDefaults.

Here is the correct way to return a mutable copy

```
    self.recentSearchesArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"RecentSearches"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: is your recentSearchesArray referring to mutable instance?

Comment: Yes - the dictionary is mutable. self.filteredParameters

Comment: Array or dictionary? How are you allocating it?

Comment: Edited the question to show allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check where place where you're setting recentSearchArray variable. Maybe you're setting it to object of `NSArray`.
Also check code where you're getting this array from `NSUserDefaults`, because `NSUserDefaults` will return object of `class` `NSArray`.

Comment: Oh, I didn;t know that. Here is how I populate the array with old data from NSUserDefaults 
 self.recentSearchesArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"RecentSearches"];

Comment: It was NSUserDefaults returning an NSArray and not a mutable copy. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with NSMutableDictionary on iOS12. I could create an NSMutableDictionary using dictionaryWithCapacity, but if I recalled one using

[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [self urlForUnsentFilesDictionary] error:&writeError];

when I later tried to add an object to it I would get that error. Worked fine on iOS13. I ended up fixing it by adding this after the initWithContentsOfURL:

dict = CFBridgingRelease( CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict, kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves) );

Hope this helps someone!